# Is there a docker image for running in place of an Azure Event Hub in a Test or CI environments?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-eventhub

Is there docker image for running in place of an Azure Event Hub in a Test or CI environment?

I want to be able to stand up a full stack with mock event hubs running as docker containers, how are people doing this? The only other option I can think of is using ARM templates to stand up and tear down actual cloud infra, which seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: I do not understand you clearly. Can you explain more detailed what you want?

Comment: @CharlesXu I want a docker image that has the same interface and basic behaviour as an event hub but without all the scalability so that I can run a development environment that isn't dependent on the Azure cloud.

Comment: I don't think there would be a single docker image that has all the functions of the Azure event hub but does not dependent on the Azure cloud. The features of Azure event hub is designed as it does with many components. So you need to create the image yourself.

Comment: I'm not asking for a container that does *all* the functionality. Just a container that offers the same interface and behaves the same minus all the scalability and consistency guarantees. It's to run a dev environment that is dependent on event hubs without having to stand up all the infrastructure. I'm pretty sure theres one for Kenesis and I was hoping to find one here. I'll ask the team on GitHub.

Comment: If you find one, please let us known. I'm looking for the same also for testing purposes.

Comment: My team is, too.  Seems like a bummer that one can get a kafka image running in a few seconds in docker, but MS doesn't even have the ability.  Kind of last decade of them.

Comment: Let's vote here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/911458-event-hubs/suggestions/39170062-docker-image-for-event-hub-in-local-dev-test-envir

Comment: Doesn't a kafka image satisfy this requirement though? Azure Eventhubs is supposed to be almost-kafka in terms of its API surface.

Comment: What's the point in putting the eventhub in a container? Why would you not use a seperate eventhub namespace for the dev flow? I realy don't see why you would exchange the paas component in the entire flow for a container, just because it's the dev environment.

Comment: Try writing acceptance tests using that shared dev resource.